# What is the problem with breasts?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-management

Until a few minutes ago, Biology SE had questions with the tag [breasts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breasts). Then, a [moderator](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/5144/chris) swiftly orphaned the tag by editing the following questions in quick succession:

- [What controls the size of breasts?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/7629)
- [Does a bigger breast give creamier milk?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21789)
- [Why do human females have permanently prominent breasts?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/51560)
- [Reference to hypothesis about breast sexual attractiveness?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58700)
- [How much blood flows to female breasts?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73516)

I did **not** create the tag [breasts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breasts). However, I do subscribe to tags from dozens of different Stack Exchange sites. If tags are removed arbitrarily, on a whim, I may not be notified when new questions on the topics that I find interesting are posted. I am **not** the only one who subscribes to tags.

1. If the tag [breasts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breasts) violates some guideline, why was the tag orphaned only now?
2. The moderator in question did not provide any reason for the removal. If a guideline is being violated, then why wasn't the relevant excerpt posted on the **edit summary**? How can the reader not acquainted with the guidelines of Biology SE distinguish effete prudishness from blind adherence to seemingly arbitrary guidelines concocted based on years of accumulated experience of moderation?
3. At the moment, tag [human-ear](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-ear) has not yet been orphaned. What do human ears have that human breasts do not? Why are some anatomical parts kosher and others haram? Would tag [human-breast](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-breast) be halal?

Answer (score 5):

Since I removed the tags, I will explain why. This tag is pretty irrelevant and had only very few questions (3 before you added it to another two questions) and is thus not helpful.

The tags are more of a general sorting, they don't have to be too specific. Also: Please avoid inventing new tags which are not or only sparsely used, as they are then relatively useless.

So, if you come along other mostly unused tags, flag the question, explain why in the text to the flag and I am happy to remove or synonymize the tags in question.